# How long will a rotaing disc will rotate if put on horizontal surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

> A uniform disc of radius $R$ is spinned to angular velocity $\omega$ and then carefully placed on a horizontal surface .How long will the disc be rotating on the the surface if friction coefficient is equal to $\mu$  ? The preasure exerted by the disc on surface can be regarded as uniform .

[image]

$$\mu mg R=\frac{mR^2}{2}\alpha$$
$$\alpha=\frac{2\mu g}{R}$$
Using $\omega_{f}=\omega_{i} +\alpha t$
$$\omega=\frac{2\mu gt}{R}$$
$$t=\frac{\omega R}{2\mu g}$$
My answer is not matching what I have done wrong ?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie I have shown my effort to do this question and I am just asking what is wrong in my concept and this is what your policy say to ask excercise question.

Comment: Did that picture come with the problem or is that something you added? I am wondering because I read the problem as the disc is set down flat on the surface instead of having the surface contact the disc at that single point.

Comment: @J.Shupperd No,I added the picture .

Comment: @J.Shupperd You are right .I made a mistake in interpreting question .

Comment: You have to integrate over rings having dr thickness and find the total torque. The rest is easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the time until the angular velocity of the disk becomes zero you can consider the loss of angular momentum and thus loss of angular velocity due to the torque exerted on the disk by the friction of the disk on the surface. You have not calculated the torque on the disk correctly. To get it right you have to integrate the infinitesimal torques of the friction force exerted on infinitesimal rings of thickness rdr at radius r. Then you get the correct torque and from this the correct answer for the time until the angular velocity becomes zero. The answer for t is then identical to the one you obtained with a numerical factor in it which is different to 1/2.